# how to bind .xml file content on a label stored on a url

Tags: wpf, templates, listbox, listbox-control

i have an xml file ,i am trying to bind it to a label but not successfull yet,i used an xmldataprovider to bind it.here is the code for the template i used.,there are several task in my xml file,i am trying to bind the 1st one.

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TaskList" Source="http://store.tymesheet.com/templates/Graphic-Designer.xml" XPath="tasks"/>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="tasktemplate1">
            <Canvas Height="40" Width="850">
                <Label Content="{Binding XPath=task[1]}"  Height="30" Width="170" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="150" Background="LightGray">

                </Label>
                <TextBox Height="30" Width="120" Canvas.Top="5" Canvas.Left="370" Background="AliceBlue"></TextBox>
                <Label Canvas.Left="500" Canvas.Top="5">$</Label>
                <Button Canvas.Top="8" Height="10" Width="30" Canvas.Left="600" ></Button>
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>
```

and the code for the listbox where the template is used is here

```
 <TabItem>
        <Canvas Height="700" Width="850">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TaskList}" x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850">
                    <ListBoxItem  Template="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}"/>
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
    </TabItem>
```

i am not getting where my binding is going wrong,any help,thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set **`ItemsSource`** and manually add **`ListBoxItem`** at same time on ListBox. Either specify ItemsSource or add items based on your condition.

In your case if you want to show only first item, remove **`ItemsSource`**  and set **`DataContext`** of **`ListBoxItem`**.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="700" Width="850">
    <ListBoxItem DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource TaskList}}"
                 Template="{StaticResource tasktemplate1}"/>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thanx ,it helped,and for every item i put it lyk dis,Xpath=task[1]/name..,task[2]/name,task[3]/name and so on...